# How to save Crontab edits?

Tags: linux, centos, crontab

I ran `crontab -e` and made some changes, now how do I save it?

Comment: [saving cron job in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9075188)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on the editor you run. `contab -e` uses the editor specified in the environment variable `$EDITOR`. Mostprobably it's `vi` or `nano`.

- In `vi` press <kbd>esc</kbd> to switch to the command mode, then type `:wq` to write (w) and quit (q).
- In `nano` press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, then press <kbd>y</kbd> for yes and provide a filename before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: You have to press `escape` first with `vi`

Comment: Awarding answer to this one based on votes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

when editing it after finishing press esc, then  type

`:wq`

and press enter, that will save the crontab and exit

or just

`:w`

will save it

Comment: You have to press `escape` first with `vi`

Answer (score 1):

This is problem of editor

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

Try running this command & then

```
crontab -e
```

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To save when done editing in crontab editing, press ESC, then hold exactly  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>

then write `wq!` press <kbd>enter</kbd> to save.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).